# Formatting a Chat Window

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to build a messaging application for iOS.  I've got a web service returning JSON, but I'm not sure how to get it to display in a scrollable, formatted area of the application.   I'm also clueless on how to get it to ping the server to check for an update, and refresh the stream if one has been posted.   Any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the basic JSON that I'm working with:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "location_id": "1",
      "origination_id": "1",
      "message": "Test message",
      "timestamp": "2014-01-16 08:57:26"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "location_id": "1",
      "origination_id": "1",
      "message": "Test Message - start",
      "timestamp": "2014-01-16 09:00:50"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "location_id": "1",
      "origination_id": "2",
      "message": "Test response",
      "timestamp": "2014-01-16 09:01:06"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "location_id": "1",
      "origination_id": "1",
      "message": "This is a test message from the API",
      "timestamp": "2014-01-16 10:23:11"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "location_id": "1",
      "origination_id": "1",
      "message": "This is a test message from the API",
      "timestamp": "2014-01-16 10:23:13"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "location_id": "1",
      "origination_id": "1",
      "message": "This is a test message from the API",
      "timestamp": "2014-01-16 10:23:22"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use APNS to receive messages or at least get notified of them. Put the JSON into an nsdictionary and display the text on a UITestView... sounds good?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can use APNS to get notifications of the updates.   However, I am pulling the information into an NSDictionary - just not sure how to get it formatted and displayed in a viewer.

Comment: There is a lot more that goes into your question than you are aware of but this should get you started. http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/ios-programming-recipe-16-populating-a-uitableview-with-data-from-the-web/

Comment: Why can't you use APNS? If you are getting the chat info from a site, it's basically the same... concat the string to be has you want... or explain your design idea

Comment: @sbarow - Taking a look at it now.

Comment: @TtheT - One of the limitations of the product itself.  It's an Enterprise deployed app, and most of the devices aren't even set up with iTunes or iCloud accounts.  Not sure if APNS would work correctly with these restrictions, but I could be wrong...

Comment: @STLCajun APNS is usable by the Enterprise account, it does not use iTunes or iCloud. To make this work you'll need to create a proper AppID in the enterprise account, instead of using the wildcard. This one helped me setting up APNS [How to test and use APNS](http://lessons.runrev.com/m/4069/l/53405)